# Does there exist a substitution to transform this differential?

Tags: calculus, substitution

Suppose I have a mix of a differential operator and a function in the form $f(x)\frac{d}{dx}$, which may be applied to a function $g(x)$ to make  $f(x)\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = f(x)g'(x)$.

However, what if I don't want to deal with $f(x)$, and I just want to find a single derivative with respect to some other coordinate system?

Then does there exist a substitution such that $f(x) \frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d}{du}$? And if so, what effect does such a transformation have on $g(x)$?

Comment: Assuming $f(x)$ is never zero: yes, such a substitution exists: you can take $u = \int \frac{1}{f(x)}\,dx$.  Moreover, by the Chain Rule, we have: $\frac{d}{du}g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)} g'(u(x))$.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense I think, maybe. How would one know what domain to take the integral over in this situation?

Comment: So if you take the, I guess, incomplete derivative that I always see in substitutions where you can somehow separate the differentials, how do you get from $u$ to $\frac{d}{du}$? Because $d(u)$ is just $du$.

Comment: The point is that the chain rule gives $\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{du}{dx} \frac{d}{du}$, from which we get that $\frac{d}{du} = \frac{1}{ \frac{du}{dx} } \frac{d}{dx}$.  So, since you want $f = \frac{1}{\frac{du}{dx}}$, we need $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{f}$, so we just need $u$ to be any anti-derivative of $1/f$.

Comment: That's interesting then, I guess I have never seen an incomplete chain rule like that before, usually there is always some $\frac{df}{dx}$ or $\frac{dv}{du}$ to complete it. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

In any interval where $f$ does not vanish we have $f(x)\frac d {dx} =\frac d {du}$ where $u(x)=\int_c^{x} \frac 1 {f(t)} dt$ where $c$ is a fixed point in the interval. [To verify this just note that $\frac {du} {dx} =\frac 1 {f(x)}$].

Comment: What happens to $g(x)$ itself? If I try to solve for $x$ I would get $x=u^{-1}(1/h')$ which doesn't seem like it matches up with your above comments.